# rules order in a prolog program

Tags: prolog

I’m a uni student and working on a AI project, we need to design a program using prolog.

we’re a beginner so its gonna be a very basic program, we aren’t required to design any interfaces or things like that.

this idea of the program is that it will show the user some ingredients(diary, meat, cheese...etc.) and after the user selects the ingredients that they want the program will suggest a recipe that can be made with the selected ingredients.

Id like to say that that we took till now is rules, loops, conditions, lists..etc.

we would just like to know how can order the rules and stuff to make it work?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Facts and rules are examined by Prolog in the order in which they are asserted or appear in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We would just like to know how we can order the rules and stuff to make it work?

Before getting to the question lets start of with some simple ideas that anyone using a pen and paper might use and then adjust it to work with Prolog.

For this question we will take it that a recipe is just a collection of ingredients and not the instructions on how to prepare the ingredients.

Here are a few simple recipes:

```erlang
tacos - shells, ground beef, spices, lettuce, cheese
steak - steak, spices
spaghetti -ground beef, spaghetti noodles, tomato sauce, spices
```

Now if we have `pork` and `spices` we can not make a recipe. If we have `steak`, and `spices` we can make steak. So lets do that in Prolog

Make a fact for the recipe:

```erlang
recipe(steak, steak, spices).
```

and a query to see if we can make a recipe:

```erlang
?- recipe(X, steak, spices).
X = steak.
```

Now someone else tries

```erlang
?- recipe(X, spices, steak).
false.
```

So clearly something is not working. From experience I know that the problem is that we are not working with a [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form). For this problem if we just sort the ingredients for the recipes and then make sure the ingredients for the quires are sorted then it will be comparing canonical forms and will fix the problem. Also if we convert the ingredients into a list we can use the built-in predicate for sorting ([sort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2)), e.g.

```erlang
?- sort([steak, spices],I).
I = [spices, steak].

?- sort([spices, steak],I).
I = [spices, steak].
```

Now using the canonical form and the ingredients as a list we get a recipe

```erlang
recipe(steak, [spices, steak]).
```

and making a query that sorts the input ingredients we get

```erlang
can_make(I,R) :-
    sort(I,Is),
    recipe(R,Is).

?- can_make([steak,spices],R).
R = steak.

?- can_make([spices,steak],R).
R = steak.
```

Adding new recipes should be easy:

```erlang
recipe(tacos, [cheese, ground_beef, lettece, shells, spices]).
recipe(spaghetti, [gound_beef, spaghetti_noddles, spices, tomato_sauce]).
```

and a quick check

```erlang
?- can_make([tomato_sauce, gound_beef, spices, spaghetti_noddles], R).
R = spaghetti.

?- can_make([spices,pork],R).
false.
```

That should get you started. Hopefully I haven't given you the complete answer to your project as it is homework and you should have something to solve.

Comment: thank you so much I really don't know how to thank you enough. Ill get started on that and Ill do my best. thanks again :)